# Migrating sales from xl to odoo using XML-RPC

Tags: python, odoo, xml-rpc

Im trying to migrate sales order from excel sheet to odoo using xmlrpc so far i have the products working,client working but when i try to insert the sale order i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oasis/PycharmProjects/somig/migrator.py", line 75, in <module>
    'validity_date':"2016-01-18",
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1243, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1602, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1283, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1316, in single_request
    return self.parse_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1493, in parse_response
    return u.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 800, in close
    raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
xmlrpclib.Fault: <Fault 1: 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 56, in xmlrpc_return\n    result = openerp.http.dispatch_rpc(service, method, params)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 114, in dispatch_rpc\n    result = dispatch(method, params)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/model.py", line 37, in dispatch\n    res = fn(db, uid, *params)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/model.py", line 173, in execute_kw\n    return execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper\n    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/model.py", line 181, in execute\n    res = execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/model.py", line 170, in execute_cr\n    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper\n    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 354, in old_api\n    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/sale/sale.py", line 232, in create\n    result = super(SaleOrder, self).create(vals)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 248, in wrapper\n    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/mail/models/mail_thread.py", line 233, in create\n    thread = super(MailThread, self).create(values)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 248, in wrapper\n    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 4157, in create\n    record = self.browse(self._create(old_vals))\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 248, in wrapper\n    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 490, in new_api\n    result = method(self._model, cr, uid, *args, **old_kwargs)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/models.py", line 4301, in _create\n    tuple([u[2] for u in updates if len(u) > 2])\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/sql_db.py", line 141, in wrapper\n    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/sql_db.py", line 220, in execute\n    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)\nProgrammingError: column "partner_id" is of type integer but expression is of type integer[]\nLINE 1: ...1, NULL, \'draft\', 6, 1, 1, \'2016-09-03 16:50:24\', ARRAY[6], ...\n                                                             ^\nHINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.\n\n'>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

my code is the following

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras
import pyexcel_xls
import pyexcel as pe
from pyexcel_xls import get_data
from datetime import datetime
import xmlrpclib
import json

url = 'http://localhost:8070'
db = 'fresh'
username = 'admin'
password = 'odoo'
#data = get_data("salesorder.xls")
#print(json.dumps(data))
records = pe.get_records(file_name="salesorder.xls")
for record in records:
    print record['name']
    names = record['name']
    print record['location']
    print record['zip']
    print record['republic']
    dates = record['date']
    print dates
    print datetime.strptime(dates,'%d/%M/%Y')
    lastdat=datetime.strptime(dates,'%d/%M/%Y')
    print record['product']
    productname= record['product']


#Check if the customer is in or else insert him
    common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))
    uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, {})
    output = common.version()
    models = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))
    partnerids = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
                    'res.partner', 'search', [[['name', '=', record['name']]]])

    if partnerids:
        print partnerids

    else:
        newpartn = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'res.partner', 'create', [{
            'name': names,
        }])
        partnerids=newpartn
        print partnerids
#Check if a product is in else insert a new product
    common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))
    uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, {})
    output = common.version()
    models = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))
    productids = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
                                   'product.product', 'search', [[['name', '=', record['product']]]])

    if productids:
        print productids

    else:
        newproduct = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'product.product', 'create', [{
            'name': productname,
            'default_code': partnerids
        }])
        productids=newproduct
        print productids



    uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, {})
    print output
    models = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))
    id = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'sale.order', 'create', [{
        'partner_id': partnerids,
     #   'name': names,
        'validity_date':"2016-01-18",
        #'payment_term_id':1,
        # 'user_id':"1"
        # 'state':"sale"


    }])
    print id
```

the 75th line is the one of validity date

Comment: just a suggestion...you shouldn't be creating a new connection every time in the for loop....move the connection outside the loop, but the error message is pretty clear, you're trying to insert a data which is not in the right format a particular field expects...you can use pdb to step through and check if you're inserting the right data types to the right fields

Comment: let me try to change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error message says:

> ProgrammingError: column "partner_id" is of type integer but expression is of type integer[].

Just give `partnerids` as an integer:

```
if partnerids:
   partnerids = partnerids[0]
   print partnerids
```

Comment: It worked the next issue is to add the products to a sales order

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you execute a search for partnerids which will result in an array. However if you do not find any you create a partner which is represented by an integer. You then assign partnerids to the partner_id in your sale.order.

Sometimes you are assigning it an integer and other times an array, depending on if you are using the partnerids from the search or the newly created partner.

If you are sure that your search for partnerids will never result in two partners having the same name then you can use the first record returned in your search which I display below. I reassigned partnerids on a second line simply to illustrate the difference.

If you are not sure if you have duplicates this will be the wrong thing to do and you should refine your search to select the correct partner.

```
    partnerids = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
                'res.partner', 'search', [[['name', '=', record['name']]]])
    partnerids = partnerids[0] if partnerids else False 

if partnerids:
    print partnerids

else:
    newpartn = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'res.partner', 'create', [{
        'name': names,
    }])
    partnerids=newpartn
```

Comment: Change your third line to `partnerids = partnerids and partnerids[0]` and i will vote it up. Because without finding any partners, your code will trigger an error.

Comment: Good eye, I changed it to resolve False if it returns an empty list of partners. Which will trigger the create function he has as a fallback. Thanks for noticing my mistake.

Comment: i dont think the issue is on the partner id because when i use an id like 1 as the value of the partner_id instead of a variable in the salesorder creator i still get the same error